# cocoa + keychain api

Tags: cocoa, digital-certificate

i am working on an app in which i have to display all the digital certificates available on my Mac laptop. 
should i use keychain to get access to these certificates??
where is the physical location of these certificates???

i want to list their names to a standard output. Please reply me with few links with examples(if possible) which i can take a look to understand and use it for my app. i have looked into Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference api but its really confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to display certificates then there already is an application - Keychain Access.app

Certificates can be physically on non-filesystem devices such as smart cards.

You most probably are interested in user certificates and not CA certificates? You should look into Keychain reference and most probably the certificate listing functions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Ruby Gem to accomplish interfacing with the Keychain Access App. It gives examples on how to use the command line program `security` which is what you can use to script the Keychain.

Here is the blogpost describing the gem: [Automating Mac OS X Keychain App](http://procbits.com/2011/10/07/automating-the-mac-os-x-keychain-app-with-ruby/).

You can browse the source here: [Keychain Manager source code](https://github.com/jprichardson/keychain_manager/blob/master/lib/keychain_manager.rb). It'll give you examples on how to use the `security` command line application.

So, to list the keychains, you just do this:

```
security list-keychains
```

Which will output something like this:

```
"/Users/jprichardson/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
"/Users/jprichardson/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
security find-certificate "/Users/jprichardson/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" -c Apple
```

For more help, run:

```
security -?
security list-keychains -?
security find-certificate -?
```

Read this too: [Apple's Man page on Security](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html)

Hope that helps.